# when I change the initial values in optim, the output $par also changes

Tags: r, optimization, mle, optim

Below is  pdf and i want to find the mles of parameters, howerver when I change the initial values in optim command, the output values of parameters also changes. If anyone can solve the issue?

```
rm(list=ls())
y=rpois(250,15)
u1=runif(1,0,1);u2=runif(1,0,1)
px = function(par) {

    a=par[1]
    beta0=par[2]
    beta1=par[3]
    beta2=par[4]


      mu=exp(beta0+beta1*u1+beta2*u2)


      l=(sqrt(4*a*mu+mu^2-2*mu+1)-mu+1)/(2*mu)
      f=(1/((1+l)^(y+2)))*(l^2+(l^a)*(((1+l)^(1-a))*gamma(y+a))/((gamma(a))*(gamma(y+1))))
      return(f)
        }

       logp=function(par){-sum(log(px(par)))}
       jk=optim(par=c(0.3,5,0.5,2.9),logp,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.1,-Inf,-Inf,- 
          Inf),upper=c(rep(Inf,4)))
          jk
   ## $par
   ## [1] 5.241496 2.506265 0.300990 2.855525
   ## 
   ## $value
   ## [1] 828.7329
   ## 
   ## $counts
   ## function gradient 
   ##       22       22 
   ## 
   ## $convergence
   ## [1] 0
   ## 
   ## $message
   ## [1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
 jk=optim(par=c(5,1,1,1),logp,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.1,-Inf,-Inf,-
 Inf),upper=c(rep(Inf,4)))
 jk
   ## $par
   ## [1] 5.241511 2.473720 1.117607 1.026283
   ## 
   ## $value
   ## [1] 828.7329
```

Comment: Probably the likelihood is multimodal and the use of different starting values omits certain maxima.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is the case, because at certain initial values , the minimum  $value also changes..

Comment: Should probably better asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), voted to migrate.

Comment: I think it is because there is more than one solution to the problem.  In other words, many different values of beta0, beta1 and beta2 can solve your problem.  If you change your method to generate some u1 and u2, the solution might be unique.